# JTextArea print dialog

Tags: java, swing, printing, dialog, jtextarea

Recently I have been working on a project which uses Java Swing to build the GUI. I want to print the text in a `JTextArea` and therefore I wrote something like

```
boolean printed = textArea.print();
```

This brings up a modal dialog. However the dialog seems to have no parent and the main frame (the one containing `textArea`) blocks the print dialog.

[image]

As you see, the print dialog (the thin line at the bottom) goes behind the main `JFrame`.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextAreaPrintBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(600,600);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                //now add JTextArea
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
                frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                try {
                    textArea.print();
                } catch (PrinterException ex) {}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bring the print dialog to front (or explicitly set the parent of the print dialog), preferably not reinventing the wheel? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know there is a line `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`. What I really want is to bring the print dialog to the very front even if the main frame is always on top.

Edit (2): I finally opted for a workaround which uses a `WindowFocusListener` and the `getOppositeWindow()` method in `WindowEvent` to obtain a reference to the print dialog. Still I resort to reflection (getting the name of the instance's class) to check whether the "opposite window" is a print dialog, or just an ordinary dialog in my application. Anyway, welcome for more elegant solutions.

Comment: your frame need to be on the top all the time?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. In fact I have thought of a workaround which invokes `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false)` before calling `print()`, and restore the setting afterwards. However, I just want to gain more control to the print dialog (e.g. I may have to further set the location), and so I am looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of this

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

So change it to `false` to see the print window.

or

Remove that line, if you don't want your main window to block other windows. Default value is false anyway.

Comment: I know, and that's why I asked how to bring the print dialog to front

Comment: If you make it always on top, then you can't because that's the expected behavior when you set it to True.

Comment: @K139, it is not true.If  you choose a JFrame with setAlwaysOnTop(true) as parent for Dialog, JDialog, or JOptionPane, they are visible. But in question case there is problem to change JTextComponent.print() dialog settings.